# trim_left implementation using string_view disallowing temporary parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, temporary-objects, string-view

I'd like to implement a non-copy data trim_left function, but would like to not allow it to accept temporary parameters to make the returned string_view is valid (the data is still alive).
I started accepting string_view as parameter, but I cannot get the way how to guarantee the data is valid.

So I make this:

```
template<typename T>
std::string_view trim_left( const T& data, std::string_view trimChars )
{
    std::string_view sv{data};
    sv.remove_prefix( std::min(sv.find_first_not_of(trimChars), sv.size()));
    return sv;
}
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>,std::string_view>::value , int > = 0>
std::string_view trim_left( const T&& data, std::string_view trimChars ) = delete;
```

My idea with the second deleted template is to disable the use of temporary object as parameters and guarantee the returned string_view is valid.

I expect that this is valid:

```
auto sv1 = trim_left("ABCHello" , "ABC");
string data = "ABCHello";
auto sv2 = trim_left( data, "ABC");
```

but not this...

```
string fee( return "ABCHello"; );
auto sv3 = trim_left( fee(), "ABC");
```

Is this the proper way to do it?
Is it possible to do this by setting a enable_if parameter on the first template and not use the second one?

Test implementation:https://wandbox.org/permlink/7q3cLGbGrX9b6q5S

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out this second implementation:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t< std::is_same<T, std::string_view>::value || !std::is_rvalue_reference_v<T&&>, int > = 0 >
std::string_view trim_left( T&& data, std::string_view trimChars )
{
    std::string_view sv{std::forward<T>(data)};
    sv.remove_prefix( std::min(sv.find_first_not_of(trimChars), sv.size()));
    return sv;
}
```

Test case: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZOaO4NDI28yQHXy9

I think is simple than the first one, and also works with the tests. Seems it's what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice. Not sure make a real difference (given that you've disabled the r-value-reference case) but given that now `T&&` is a universal reference, it seems to me you should forward `data` (I mean: `std::string_view sv{std::forward<T>(data)};`)

Comment: Thanks @max66, I edited and modified incorporating your recommendation

Answer (score 1):

Well... given that `trim_left()` doesn't change `data`, I suppose that you can write the main `trim_left()` receiving a `T const &`

```
template <typename T>
std::string_view trim_left (T const & data, std::string_view trimChars)
 {
   std::string_view sv{data};
   sv.remove_prefix( std::min(sv.find_first_not_of(trimChars), sv.size()));
   return sv;
 }
```

Then you can add an auxiliary `trim_left()` that receive a `T &` and call the main version adding `const` to `data`

```
template <typename T>
std::string_view trim_left (T & data, std::string_view tc)
 { return trim_left((T const &)data, tc); }
```

Last a deleted `trim_left()` for universal reference

```
template <typename T>
std::string_view trim_left (T &&, std::string_view) = delete;
```

Now you have

```
auto sv1 = trim_left("ABCHello" , "ABC"); // OK: main version (const &)

std::string data = "ABCHello";
auto sv2 = trim_left( data, "ABC"); // OK: auxiliary version (&)

// auto sv3 = trim_left( fee(), "ABC"); // compiler error: deleted version
```

Comment: I find it interesting that you need the `T &` version.  Presumably, `T &&` is a better match than `T const &` when T is not `const`.

Comment: @PaulSanders - Not really a C++ references nightmare expert but... given that is referred to a template, `&&` is a "universal reference", so intercept almost all and is a bad match when another template is an exact (reference) match. But when you have a `const &` template and a `&&` template, a non-const reference isn't an exact match for the `const &` so is intercepted by the universal reference. So you need an auxiliary non-const reference version to intercept this case.

Comment: Thanks, but even in my original proposal, the second test (sv2) is also processed by const &, so I don't understand why I need to add the T& alternative.

Comment: I added a link to the test case. The code I proposed I understand that already works well, but I'd like to know if it is the right way to do it, or if there a better way to disable temporary parameters to be used.

Comment: @SNJ - This is a possible way, non the only way. In this way, I avoid the SFINAE part to disable the `T&&` version. The `T&` is used to avoid that the second case is intercepted by the `T&&` version. Anyway, your SFINAE based solution seems really good to me.